# On React-Redux Web Application, Can I reduce the Ajax calling times?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For 3 months I have been learning about React-Redux. Really Redux is very good idea. While I am reviewing about the redux, I got my opinion that Redux seems to be a global variable which is defined as **STORE**. So on React-Redux application, every component, every custom hooks and others can access the global variable **STORE** to get and set.

By this thought, I believe that I can reduce the Ajax calling times.
For example, Let’s suppose that there are 2 pages such as users page and rooms page.
users page will display the user list, and rooms page will display the user list in each rooms.

users page (One ajax calling)

- #1. getting the user list

rooms page(Two ajax calling)

- #1 getting the user list
- #2 getting the room list with room-user relation infos

**before, whenever the page is loaded (componentDidMount), I made the users page and rooms page to call the ajax for getting the data.
But I would like to call the ajax only one time with Redux. So at only the first time of page load, the ajax call will work.**
I think that it is possible with Redux, because Redux store is working as a global variable.

But I have a problem with this idea. The problem is Data sync.

Let’s suppose there are 2 admin users (**Admin#1**, **Admin#2**) who can edit the server data.

Now I logged in with **Admin#1**, and I visited the users page and rooms page. So the user data and room data will save on the Redux Store. After that, the ajax call never need for users and rooms data.

But at this time, **Admin#2** added/deleted some of users.

At this case, how can **Admin#1** get the synced data?

I think that the websocket seems to be good solution. But websocket function for the whole web app is very difficult.

So what is the best solution for my problem?

Comment: Maybe make some sort of frequent heartbeat check to your API which just returns the timestamp of last modification rather than a whole dump of data.  You would fetch the data only if the modification was more recent than your last fetch.

Comment: In my case, I memoize some API calls that don't change often.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try socketio. When a client delete/add new user, it will broadcast an event to other clients (webapp). You just have to implement a static socketIO client and exports all important functions (also think about callback too) so that you can import and use them in your components